# Add parameter description when converting a Dataclass to BaseModel

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi, pydantic

I need to add a [description](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#declare-more-metadata) to a FastAPI query parameter, which I pass to the endpoint *through a dataclass*, in order to display it in OpenAPI/Swagger UI (auto-documentation).
How can I do it?

I tried through `metadata` in `fields`, but it has no effect (no description for `x` was added):

[image]

To my understanding the `dataclass` object is used to create a pydantic [`BaseModel`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#basic-model-usage) object, which is then used by FastAPI.

---

Here's my **unsuccessful** code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    x: str = field(default=None, metadata={'description': 'descr of x'})


@app.get("/", )
async def root(f: MyDataclass = Depends()):
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `field` from dataclass, use `Query` from pydantic:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query

app = FastAPI()


@dataclass
class MyDataclass:
    x: str = Query(default=None, description='descr of x')
```

[image]